# Is it secure to have only external server certificate on Gateway in Istio?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

Using Istio 1.11. I've got these external certificates: server certificate, private key, intermediate cert, and root cert.

I have placed the server certificate at the Gateway level as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway 
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: tls-secret
    hosts:
    - example.com
```

Is this secure and does it mean that from the Gateway to the pod it would fall back on MTLS or there is no encryption all the way to the pod? Or do I need to somehow implement my external cacerts for MTLS? I'm not finding any documentation on this.

With this approach, when showing the certs with openssl:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername example.com -connect example.com:443
```

I am getting these errors:

```
20:unable to get local issuer certificate
21:unable to verify the first certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it secure to have only external server certificate on Gateway in
> Istio?

Yes its secure.

```
 tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: tls-secret
```

> Is this secure and does it mean that from the Gateway to the pod it
> would fall back on MTLS

Above configuration is for one way mTLS, for traffic from external system to application pod. if this needs to be enabled for two way mTLS then it can be changed to "mode: Mutual" instead of "mode: Simple".  Please refer [istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/) documentation for more details.

> or there is no encryption all the way to the pod?

Once tls protocol is configured in gateway the communication is encrypted from client to server.